# Using The [] Operator Efficiently With C++ unordered_map

Tags: c++, unordered-map

Firstly could someone clarify whether in C++ the use of the [] operator in conjunction with an unordered_map for lookups wraps a call to the find() method, or is using the [] operator quicker than find()?

Secondly, in the following piece of code I suspect in cases where the key is not already in the unordered_map I am performing a second look up by way of the line `map[key] = value` in order to replace the default value created there by using the [] operator when a key is not present.

Is that true, and if so is there a way (perhaps by use of pointers or something) that I might only perform one look up in any case (perhaps by storing the address of where to place a value/read a value from) and still achieve the same functionality? Obviously this would be a useful efficiency improvement if so.

Here is the modified code excerpt:

```
    int stored_val = map[key]; // first look up. Does this wrap ->find()??

    // return the corresponding value if we find the key in the map - ie != 0
    if (stored_val) return stored_val;

    // if not in map
    map[key] = value; 
       /* second (unnecessary?) look up here to find position for newly 
          added key entry */

   return value;
```

Answer (score 50, accepted):

[`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/operator_at) will insert an entry for you with a default-constructed value, if one isn't already there. It is equivalent to, but will probably be implemented more efficiently than:

```
iterator iter = map.find(key);

if(iter == map.end())
{
    iter = map.insert(value_type(key, int())).first;
}

return *iter;
```

`operator[]` can be quicker than doing the work manually with [`find()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) and [`insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/insert), because it can save having to re-hash the key.

One way you can work around having multiple lookups in your code is to take a reference to the value:

```
int &stored_val = map[key];

// return the corresponding value if we find the key in the map - ie != 0
if (stored_val) return stored_val;

// if not in map
stored_val = value;

return value;
```

Note that if the value doesn't exist in the map, `operator[]` will default-construct and insert one. So while this will avoid multiple lookups, it might actually be slower if used with a type that is slower to default-construct + assign than to copy- or move-construct.

With `int` though, which cheaply default-constructs to 0, you might be able to treat 0 as a magic number meaning empty. This looks like it might be the case in your example.

If you have no such magic number, you've got two options. What you should use depends on how expensive it is for you to compute the value.

First, when hashing the key is cheap but computing the value is expensive, `find()` may be the best option. This will hash twice but only compute the value when needed:

```
iterator iter = map.find(key);

// return the corresponding value if we find the key in the map
if(iter != map.end()) return *iter;

// if not in map
map.insert(value_type(key, value));

return value;
```

But if you've got the value already, you can do it very efficiently -- perhaps slighty more efficiently than using a reference + magic number as above:

```
pair<iterator,bool> iter = map.insert(value_type(key, value));
return *iter.first;
```

If the bool returned by `map.insert(value_type)` is true, the item was inserted. Otherwise, it already existed and no modifications were made. The iterator returned points to the inserted or existing value in the map. For your simple example, this may be the best option.

Comment: +1: The use of a reference is what I do normally, readable, compact and also efficient

Comment: Theoretically I assumed a way such as this might exist so I am very grateful to you for showing me how to do it and adding your expertise. This should save me a lot of execution time given that I use this functionality several 100,000 times during execution. Many thanks

Comment: Also, in reference to your edit: 0 is a meaningful number in the context of my program but when I store the first value I take note of its key (using static global var) and upon subsequent calls if stored_val equals 0 I will do a key check to see if the current key equals the key that maps to the value 0. This gets round the problem, but thanks for the valid concern.

Comment: `operator[]` can also be slower than `find()` plus `insert()`, because it must default construct the object, then assign to it, where as `find()` plus `insert()` constructs (with probably an additional copy construct in C++03).  Whether that is more or less expensive than rehashing (or whether the implementation has to recalculate the hash for a value it's just looked up) will depend.  You can't really know in advance.

Comment: Well in the map I am using primitive-types so does this avoid the constructing of an object you mention that I imagine would occur in maps using reference types?

Comment: Indeed, it does depend very much on the expense of the value type's constructors.  For `int` as he is using, `operator[]` should be best.

Comment: It will construct `int` -- this just sets it to 0.  Probably faster than rehashing the key.

Answer (score 10):

You can both check if an element exists, *and* insert a new element if it does not exist, with the special `insert` function that returns a `pair<iterator, bool>` in which the boolean value tells you if the value has been actually inserted. For example, the code [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/insert/):

```
  unordered_map<char, int> mymap;
  pair<unordered_map<char,int>::iterator,bool> ret;

  // first insert function version (single parameter):;
  mymap.insert ( pair<char,int>('z',200) );
  ret=mymap.insert (pair<char,int>('z',500) ); 
  if (ret.second==false)
  {
    cout << "element 'z' already existed";
    cout << " with a value of " << ret.first->second << endl;
  }
```

The code here inserts the pair `<'z',200>` into the map if it does not exist. It returns the iterator where it is inserted if the value of the second element of the pair returned is true, or, it returns the iterator where the element actually was, if the second element of the pair is false.

Comment: This is a useful answer so thank you for your input. I think I am going to go with one of the others that utilises storing a reference because it looks cleaner in terms of readability (I'm not sure of the difference in efficiency obviously!), but thank you all the same. Your help is gratefully appreciated.

Comment: Always inserting is not possible in the (usual) case that calculating the value is expensive. In that case, the map is used to avoid recalculating the value - an advantage your code completely lacks.

Comment: @Sjoerd, as per the question, it seemed that calculating the value is not the critic time consuming task of this process. If not, why trying to optimize one or two accesses to the (hash) map, that will be mostly O(1)?

Comment: @Diego Good point, although calculating the hash might be time consuming as well.

Comment: @Diego Note that a time consuming calculation is also O(1), as it most likely does not depend on the size of the unordered_map. So always recalculating is O(1) - even when recalculating takes a very long time.

Answer (score 2):

> Firstly could someone clarify whether in C++ the use of the [] operator in conjunction with an unordered_map for lookups wraps a call to the Find() method, or is using the [] operator quicker than Find()?

There is no rule for that.  An implementation of `[]` could use `find()`, it could perform the lookup by itself or it could delegate the lookup to some private method that is also used by `find()` internally.

There is also no guarantee on which one is faster.  `find()` involves an overhead in constructing and returning an iterator, whereas `[]` will probably be slower if the key does not exist, as it inserts a new value in this case.

> (...) is there a way (perhaps by use of pointers or something) that I might only perform one look up in any case (...)

If the key is not in the map, `[]` will insert a new default-constructed value, and return *a reference*. Therefore, you could store that reference to save the second lookup:

```
int& stored_val = map[key];  // Note the reference

if (stored_val) return stored_val;

// Use the reference to save a second lookup.
stored_val = value; 

return value;
```

Comment: This looks like exactly what I was after, many thanks indeed. Just out of interest, if & is 'the address of', then why is it not correct to say *stored_val = value; whereby * denotes 'the value stored at'? Please correct my possibly misunderstanding of the syntax here!

Comment: `&` is used both for "address of" (get a pointer) and for references (implicit pointer) in C++.  Here, `int&` is a *reference*, not a pointer (this would be `int*`).  You don't have to dereference references, so there is no need to write `*stored_value = ...`.