# Most efficient way to use C++11 unordered_map in a read/write

Tags: c++, c++11, std, unordered-map

In a part of my program, I want to update a given value of an `unordered_map`. The problem can be simplified like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::unordered_map <unsigned long, int> map;
    unsigned long i = 1;
    std::string s;
    while (i != 0) {
        std::cout << "Give me an unsigned long" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> s;
        i = strtoul(s.c_str(), NULL, 0);
        if (map.find(i) == map.end()) map[i] = 1;
        else if (map[i] < static_cast<unsigned long>(-1)) map[i] += 1;
    }
}
```

(Of course, my program does not store user input data, it is just for illustration purposes. My program actually stores integer-encoded strings on a 4-letter alphabet. I need hashes, and not trees, to do so.)

As you see, I need to check the presence of a key, and update it. Since I am storing more than 1 billion integers, I would like to know the most efficient way to do so.

I saw [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6897737/using-the-operator-efficiently-with-c-unordered-map), but it does not mention value update.

Many thanks to you all.

Comment: note that in instead of casting, you may want to use `std::numeric_limits<decltype(map[i])>::max()`

Comment: @phresnel: Very true. I am still not very familiar with C++11 limits. Yet, would it compute `map[i]`, then get its type (something I do not want), or is it equivalent to `std::numeric_limits<unsigned long>::max()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int &value = map[key];
if (value != static_cast<unsigned long>(-1)) ++value;
```

If `key` is not present in the map, `value` will be value-initialized to `0`, so will take the correct value of `1` after increment.

Comment: Simple and elegant! Yet, 2 things I did not know: initialization to 0, and the reference to the value the map (although I should have known).